# Limitations on executing javascript through Selenium on Android in Browserstack?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, jwplayer, video.js, browserstack

I'm having hard times making videos play with the following stack: Selenium + BrowserStack + Android + JavascriptExecutor + VideoJS Player/JWPlayer. Let's take VideosJS player as an example.

Please note, that's *not Appium*.

- When I click the "Play Video" button with Selenium (`playBackButton.click();`) - it starts the playback. **Both on desktop and mobile**
- When I click with Javascript (`executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", playBackButton);`) - it doesn't start the playback **on mobile**. Works fine on desktop.
- When I try to execute the native method `.play()` - it doesn't work **on mobile**, works fine on desktop.

What gives?

Additional details (not sure they're needed, but still)

```
String xpath = "//*[@title='Play Video']";
playBackButton = _webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
String script = "function sleep(ms) {" +
                "return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); }" +
                "async function demo() {" +
                "await sleep(5000);" +
                "try{" +
                "jwplayer().play();}" +
                "catch(err) {" +
                "console.log('error');}" +
                "try{" +
                "var videoId = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].getAttribute('id');" +
                "videojs(videoId).play();}" +
                "catch(err){" +
                "console.log('error');}}" +
                "demo();";
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) _webDriver;
//executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", playBackButton);
//executor.executeScript(script);
//playBackButton.click();
```

Comment: Is the javascript method you mentioned native to mobile browsers? I mean does it work out-of-the-box on mobile browsers?

Comment: Not sure about the click. The `play()` one is native though as it is the way player works.